# How can I subtract from an array the subsequent number in the same array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matplotlib

Let's say I have an array:

```
A = [20, 18, 25, 33, 32, 22, 14, 20, 24, 33, 66, 70, 60, 50]
```

How do I get an array `B` that is the first minus the second, the second minus the third so on to get this:

```
B = [2, -7, -8, 1, 10, 8, -6, -4, -9, -33, -4, 10, 10]
```

and then plot `B`?

Thank you for your help!

I have tried to do:

```
B = ([(n+1)-n] for n in zip(A))
```

but when I try to plot the graph it gives back the error:

```
matplotlib does not support generators as input
```

Also to explain better the array is much longer and in decimals, this is just an approximation of what the actual problem is, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your code with:

```
B = [a-b for a,b in zip(A, A[1:])]
```

On the other note, with this kind of operations, you should try with numpy, for example: `np.diff`:

```
import numpy as np
B = np.diff(A[::-1])[::-1]
```

or, similar to your idea:

```
A = np.array(A)

B = A[:-1] - A[1:]
```